# Multiple files uploading in php and mysql with Multiple input fields

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me.. i have two textbox and and five inputs to upload the files... everything is working good.. the problem is if i skip experience certificate to upload file it will not Insert anything in db.. but when i attach all the documents Resume, Photo, Passport Front, Passport Back and Experience Certificate it is saving and uploading the attachments into db...

please help me how to make Experience Certificate is Not Mandatory..

Please help.. Thanks in Advance..

```
<form name="companyname" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    First Name: <input name="firstname" type="text">
    Last Name: <input name="lastname" type="text">

    Resume:* <input type="file" name='resumefile'/>
    Photo:* <input type="file" name='photofile'/>
    Passport Front:* <input type="file" name='passportfront'/>
    Passport Back:* <input type="file" name='passportback'/>
    Experience Certificate: <input type="file" name='experience'/>

    <button type="submit" name="misbtn">Save</button>
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
require ("config.php"); 
if(isset($_POST['misbtn']))
{

$resfile = $_FILES['resumefile'];
$picfile = $_FILES['photofile'];
$ppfrnt = $_FILES['passportfront'];
$ppbck = $_FILES['passportback'];
$exp = $_FILES['experience'];

if(($resfile['type'] && $picfile['type'] && $ppfrnt['type'] && $ppbck['type'] && $exp['type'] == 'image/gif')
|| ($resfile['type'] && $picfile['type'] && $ppfrnt['type'] && $ppbck['type'] && $exp['type'] == 'image/jpeg')
|| ($resfile['type'] && $picfile['type'] && $ppfrnt['type'] && $ppbck['type'] && $exp['type'] == 'image/png')
|| ($resfile['type'] && $picfile['type'] && $ppfrnt['type'] && $ppbck['type'] && $exp['type'] == 'application/msword')
|| ($resfile['type'] && $picfile['type'] && $ppfrnt['type'] && $ppbck['type'] && $exp['type'] == 'application/pdf')
&& ($resfile['size'] && $picfile['size'] && $ppfrnt['size'] && $ppbck['size'] && $exp['size'] < 10000000))
{
    if($resfile['error'] || $picfile['error'] || $ppfrnt['error'] || $ppbck['error'] || $exp['error'] > 0)
    {
        echo "retrun code:" . $resfile['error'] .$picfile['error'] .$ppfrnt['error'] .$ppbck['error'] .$exp['error'];
    }



  // if file exists i am renaming it random number  
    else if(file_exists('upload/'.$resfile['name']) || ('upload/'.$picfile['name']) || ('upload/'.$ppfrnt['name']) || ('upload/'.$ppbck['name']) || ('upload/'.$exp['name']))
    {

        $temp = explode(".", $resfile["name"]);
        $temp1 = explode(".", $picfile["name"]);
        $temp2 = explode(".", $ppfrnt["name"]);
        $temp3 = explode(".", $ppbck["name"]);
        $temp4 = explode(".", $exp["name"]);
        $newfilename = round(rand(0000, 9999)) . '.' . end($temp);
        $newfilename1 = round(rand(0000, 9999)) . '.' . end($temp1);
        $newfilename2 = round(rand(0000, 9999)) . '.' . end($temp2);
        $newfilename3 = round(rand(0000, 9999)) . '.' . end($temp3);
        $newfilename4 = round(rand(0000, 9999)) . '.' . end($temp4);
        move_uploaded_file($resfile["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $newfilename);
        move_uploaded_file($picfile["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $newfilename1);
        move_uploaded_file($ppfrnt["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $newfilename2);
        move_uploaded_file($ppbck["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $newfilename3);
        move_uploaded_file($exp["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $newfilename4);

        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO maininfosheet(fname, lname, resume, photo, ppfrontattach, ppbckattach, expcertificate)
                            VALUES ('{$_POST['ppnumber']}',
                                    '{$_POST['select_agentname']}',
                                    '{$_POST['firstname']}',
                                    '{$_POST['lastname']}',
                                    '{$newfilename}',
                                    '{$newfilename1}',
                                    '{$newfilename2}',
                                    '{$newfilename3}',
                                    '{$newfilename4}')");

        if ($sql)
        {
            echo "successfully insert this record";
        }

    }

} else {


$sql1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO maininfosheet(fname, lname)
                    VALUES ('{$_POST['firstname']}',
                            '{$_POST['lastname']}')");
if ($sql1)
{
    echo "successfully insert this record";
}

}
}
?>
```

Comment: If you have no idea whatsoever why it is, you should probably go back to learning some basics. The execution never enters that really ugly huge if statement when no experience is sent with the form.

Comment: Your query, if you get that far is also wrong. You have 7 columns mentioned and 9 data items passed into the query. The order of the column names do not match the order of the data items, so at best you will get the wrong data in each column on your database, and at worst the query will fail, with an error message that you never bother to diaplay.

Comment: As you are obviously just learning please dont use the `mysql_` database extension it is deprecated (soon to be removed) from PHP completely, Instead put your energies into learning either the `mysqli_` or `PDO` database extensions.

Comment: You're relying on it existing in your condition `&& $exp['type'] == 'image/gif'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$exp = $_FILES['experience'];
```

It does not work because you are relying on that file being one of several types

In your condition you have `&& $exp['type'] ==` different filetypes, and you have `$exp['size'] < 10000000`, expecting it to always exist.

Only include that condition if the file exists. But your condition is untidy and repetative so let's fix that too.

```
$resfile = $_FILES['resumefile'];
$picfile = $_FILES['photofile'];
$ppfrnt = $_FILES['passportfront'];
$ppbck = $_FILES['passportback'];

// see if $exp exists
if (isset($_FILES['experience']) && isset($_FILES['experience']['type'])){
    switch ($_FILES['experience']['type']){ // check type
        case 'image/gif':
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/png':
        case 'application/msword':
        case 'application/pdf':
            $exp = $_FILES['experience']; // set it
            break;
        default: // otherwise set to false
            $exp = false;
    }
}

// Tidier condition (expanded for readability)
if ( $resfile['type'] 
    && $picfile['type'] 
    && $ppfrnt['type'] 
    && $ppbck['type'] 
    /* not this - it's not required // && $exp */
    && $resfile['size'] 
    && $picfile['size'] 
    && $ppfrnt['size'] 
    && $ppbck['size'] 
    && (!$exp || $exp['size'] < 10000000) /* ok if false or small enough */
){ /* etc */
```

**Further on, don't try and use `$exp` to save a file when it == false.**

P.S. Your code will throw up notices because you're not using `isset`.